# How to put images in ListView javafx

Tags: java, listview, javafx

In my ListView **myList**, I want each item(String) to have a mini photo next to it.

Here is my how my ListView **myList** is defined:

```
ListView<String> myList = new ListView<String>();

SearchResultList.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>,ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override 
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
            return new ColorRectCell();
        }
    }
);
```

I read you must specify a *cell factory* which updates each item in list. However I don't know how this all works, This is the code where I specify my **cell factory**

```
static class ColorRectCell extends ListCell<String> {
   @Override
   public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            Image rect = new Image("huisteken.jpg");
            ImageView rec = new ImageView(rect);
            if (item != null) { 
                System.out.println("testing" + item +"######");

                setGraphic(rec);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            }

    }
 }
```

Please, any ideas or tips are welcome.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @James_D This puts a photo wherever there is row with text info. I want that photo to be next to the text not replace it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to accomplish this is to set the Cells text to null and to make Graphic contain a Hbox containing both picture and text. So make your updateItem look like this:

```
@Override
void updateItem(final String item, final boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    // if null, display nothing
    if (empty || item == null) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
        return;
    }

    setText(null);

    Label textLabel = new Label(item + " ");

    final HBox hbox = new HBox();
    hbox.setSpacing(5);

    Label iconLabel = new Label();
    iconLabel.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("huisteken.jpg")));

    hbox.getChildren().addAll(iconLabel, textLabel);
    setGraphic(hbox);
}
```

`